# I can't see all librabries in my intellij idea external library folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Question: Why aren't my libraries in Intellij IDEA showing up underneath the SDK in the External Libraries folder??

## EDIT

The external library folder does only contain libraries which are not in the project structure/path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click the libs you added in `Project Structur --> Libraries`, click `Add to Modules...`
After that, make sure the libs are shown in `Project Structure --> Modules --> Dependencies`
Hope this helps you.

Comment: If the libraries are not added automatically do we have any option to tell  save all maven dependency of mvn clean install  in to .idea>liberares folder?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled IDEA and now everything works properly.
Seems to be an older version file which didn't allow the ide to show everything correctly.

## EDIT

After a deeper look at it I found out that it won't show up in the External Libraries folder if you have it in a Project folder. :D
The meaning of external library is important.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the .idea > libraries folder if there is no library and jar .xml is mention then  go to --

```
  Files > Settings > plugin...> Maven > importing
```

and check which version of jdk is mentioned there. if the  jdk is not same as the

```
   project structure > SDK
```

then make it same and then do

```
 mvn clean install
```

it will solve the issue. This solution works for me.

[image]